# Time complexity of n factorial

Tags: time, time-complexity

I have the following problem but I have no idea how to prove it

```
n! is
    Select one or more:
 a. O(n^{3}) 
 b. O((n/2)^{n}) 
 c. O((n/3)^{n}) 
 d. O((n+1)!) 
 e. O(n^{n})
 f. O(2^{n})
```

I was thinking of using the property that f(x) ∈ O (g(x)) if and only if there is a value x0 and a constant c>0 such that for all x >= x0 f(x)<=c*g(x)

That would mean for the last one:

```
n! <= c*2^{n}, for all n>=n0
n!/2^n <=c, for all n>=n0
```

Is it correct if I state here that the inequality is false as n!/2^n tends to infinity and c is just a constant?

Applying this logic I got that n! is b.,c.,d.,e. but I'm not sure this is correct.

Comment: Are you regarding the cost of multiplication as constant time or as some other function?  For the range of factorials that can be represented in 32-bit or 64-bit integers, the cost of N! is O(N) multiplications.  When the time taken to do the multiply is more complex because the values are too big to fit into the fixed-size registers in the chip, but you are still doing exact representations, the time taken to do the multiplications increases as the numbers increase.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think the question is not so much about the complexity of computing n! as much as how n! as a function compares to these other functions.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that n! ≠ O(2<sup>n</sup>) for precisely the reason you've mentioned.

For (b) and (c), you'll need a more nuanced approach. Stirling's approximation says that

> n! = Θ(√n (n / e)<sup>n</sup>)

This might be useful in evaluating the limit of n! over quantities (b) and (c). If you do, you'll see that only one of the two bounds holds, not both.

And yes, (d) and (e) are correct.

Hope this helps!

Comment: lim(n->∞)   (sqrt(n)*(n/e)^n)/(n!) = 1/sqrt(2 π)